# Pythagoras triples equation $px+qy+rz=X^2$

Tags: number-theory, pythagorean-triples

Pythagoras theorem $$a^2+b^2=c^2$$

Let $(p,q,r)$ and $(x,y,z)$ are any two pair of Pythagoras triples.

**We have $px+qy+rz=X^2$.**

For examples:

$(3,4,5)$ and $(20,21,29)$ then $\color{blue}{3\times20+4\times21+5\times29=17^2}$

$(8,15,17)$ and $(9,40,41)$ then $\color{red}{8\times9+15\times41+17\times41=37^2}$

$(48,55,73)$ and $(65,72,97)$ then $\color{blue}{48\times65+55\times72+73\times97=119^2}$

$(19,180,181)$ and $(28,195,197)$ then $\color{red}{19\times28+180\times195+181\times197=267^2}$

$(21,220,221)$ and $(120,209,241)$ then $\color{blue}{21\times120+220\times209+221\times241=319^2}$

$(69,260,269)$ and $(68,285,293)$ then $\color{red}{69\times68+260\times285+269\times293=397^2}$

Noticing that $X$ seems to be of ONLY of prime number.

Here I found an eample proof to be false, $X$ is not always a prime number!

$(20,21,29)$ and $(11,60,61)$ then $\color{green}{20\times11+21\times60+29\times61=57^2=(3\times17)^2}$

My question is: **Are there infinitely many of this equation, $px+qy+rz=X^2$?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are infinitely many primitive sextuples as requested. All that is necessary is to pair the odd legs times the even legs. Here are integers $a,b,c,d,$ $a > b \geq 1,$ $\gcd(a,b) = 1,$ $a+b$ is odd, $c > d \geq 1,$ $\gcd(c,d) = 1,$ $c+d$ is odd.
$$  a^2 - b^2, \; \; 2ab, \; \; a^2 + b^2  $$
$$  2cd, \; \; c^2 - d^2, \; \; c^2 + d^2  $$
$$ \color{red}{ 2cd \left(a^2 - b^2\right)   + 2  a  b  \left( c^2 - d^2\right) + \left(a^2 + b^2\right)  \left( c^2 + d^2\right) = \left( a  (c + d) + b  (c - d) \right)^2} $$

The main ordering in the computer run below is that $r < z.$ I think I finally got it to list everything with the bounds I put on $a,b,c,d.$ Given **any two** distinct primitive triples, your construction can be made to work, just match $p \equiv y \pmod 2,$ $q \equiv x \pmod 2$ in order to write the multiplications as you wanted.

```
    p    q    r             x    y    z           sqrt       a    b      c    d
    3    4    5            112   15  113            31       2    1      8    7
    3    4    5             12   35   37            19       2    1      6    1
    3    4    5             12    5   13            11       2    1      3    2
    3    4    5            132   85  157            39       2    1     11    6
    3    4    5            140   51  149            37       2    1     10    7
    3    4    5            144   17  145            35       2    1      9    8
    3    4    5             16   63   65            25       2    1      8    1
    3    4    5            176   57  185            41       2    1     11    8
    3    4    5            180   19  181            39       2    1     10    9
    3    4    5             20   21   29            17       2    1      5    2
    3    4    5             20   99  101            31       2    1     10    1
    3    4    5            220   21  221            43       2    1     11   10
    3    4    5             24    7   25            15       2    1      4    3
    3    4    5             28   45   53            23       2    1      7    2
    3    4    5             36   77   85            29       2    1      9    2
    3    4    5             40    9   41            19       2    1      5    4
    3    4    5             44  117  125            35       2    1     11    2
    3    4    5             48   55   73            27       2    1      8    3
    3    4    5             56   33   65            25       2    1      7    4
    3    4    5             60   11   61            23       2    1      6    5
    3    4    5             60   91  109            33       2    1     10    3
    3    4    5             72   65   97            31       2    1      9    4
    3    4    5             80   39   89            29       2    1      8    5
    3    4    5              8   15   17            13       2    1      4    1
    3    4    5             84   13   85            27       2    1      7    6
    3    4    5             88  105  137            37       2    1     11    4
    5   12   13            112   15  113            47       3    2      8    7
    5   12   13             12   35   37            31       3    2      6    1
    5   12   13            132   85  157            61       3    2     11    6
    5   12   13            140   51  149            57       3    2     10    7
    5   12   13            144   17  145            53       3    2      9    8
    5   12   13             16   63   65            41       3    2      8    1
    5   12   13            176   57  185            63       3    2     11    8
    5   12   13            180   19  181            59       3    2     10    9
    5   12   13             20   21   29            27       3    2      5    2
    5   12   13             20   99  101            51       3    2     10    1
    5   12   13            220   21  221            65       3    2     11   10
    5   12   13             24    7   25            23       3    2      4    3
    5   12   13             28   45   53            37       3    2      7    2
    5   12   13             36   77   85            47       3    2      9    2
    5   12   13             40    9   41            29       3    2      5    4
    5   12   13             44  117  125            57       3    2     11    2
    5   12   13             48   55   73            43       3    2      8    3
    5   12   13             56   33   65            39       3    2      7    4
    5   12   13             60   11   61            35       3    2      6    5
    5   12   13             60   91  109            53       3    2     10    3
    5   12   13             72   65   97            49       3    2      9    4
    5   12   13             80   39   89            45       3    2      8    5
    5   12   13              8   15   17            21       3    2      4    1
    5   12   13             84   13   85            41       3    2      7    6
    5   12   13             88  105  137            59       3    2     11    4
    7   24   25            112   15  113            63       4    3      8    7
    7   24   25             12   35   37            43       4    3      6    1
    7   24   25            132   85  157            83       4    3     11    6
    7   24   25            140   51  149            77       4    3     10    7
    7   24   25            144   17  145            71       4    3      9    8
    7   24   25             16   63   65            57       4    3      8    1
    7   24   25            176   57  185            85       4    3     11    8
    7   24   25            180   19  181            79       4    3     10    9
    7   24   25             20   21   29            37       4    3      5    2
    7   24   25             20   99  101            71       4    3     10    1
    7   24   25            220   21  221            87       4    3     11   10
    7   24   25             28   45   53            51       4    3      7    2
    7   24   25             36   77   85            65       4    3      9    2
    7   24   25             40    9   41            39       4    3      5    4
    7   24   25             44  117  125            79       4    3     11    2
    7   24   25             48   55   73            59       4    3      8    3
    7   24   25             56   33   65            53       4    3      7    4
    7   24   25             60   11   61            47       4    3      6    5
    7   24   25             60   91  109            73       4    3     10    3
    7   24   25             72   65   97            67       4    3      9    4
    7   24   25             80   39   89            61       4    3      8    5
    7   24   25             84   13   85            55       4    3      7    6
    7   24   25             88  105  137            81       4    3     11    4
    8   15   17            105   88  137            67       4    1     11    4
    8   15   17             11   60   61            45       4    1      6    5
    8   15   17            117   44  125            61       4    1     11    2
    8   15   17             13   84   85            53       4    1      7    6
    8   15   17             15  112  113            61       4    1      8    7
    8   15   17             17  144  145            69       4    1      9    8
    8   15   17             19  180  181            77       4    1     10    9
    8   15   17             21   20   29            31       4    1      5    2
    8   15   17             21  220  221            85       4    1     11   10
    8   15   17             33   56   65            47       4    1      7    4
    8   15   17             35   12   37            33       4    1      6    1
    8   15   17             39   80   89            55       4    1      8    5
    8   15   17             45   28   53            41       4    1      7    2
    8   15   17             51  140  149            71       4    1     10    7
    8   15   17             55   48   73            49       4    1      8    3
    8   15   17             57  176  185            79       4    1     11    8
    8   15   17             63   16   65            43       4    1      8    1
    8   15   17             65   72   97            57       4    1      9    4
    8   15   17              7   24   25            29       4    1      4    3
    8   15   17             77   36   85            51       4    1      9    2
    8   15   17             85  132  157            73       4    1     11    6
    8   15   17             91   60  109            59       4    1     10    3
    8   15   17              9   40   41            37       4    1      5    4
    8   15   17             99   20  101            53       4    1     10    1
    9   40   41            112   15  113            79       5    4      8    7
    9   40   41            132   85  157            105       5    4     11    6
    9   40   41            140   51  149            97       5    4     10    7
    9   40   41            144   17  145            89       5    4      9    8
    9   40   41             16   63   65            73       5    4      8    1
    9   40   41            176   57  185            107       5    4     11    8
    9   40   41            180   19  181            99       5    4     10    9
    9   40   41             20   99  101            91       5    4     10    1
    9   40   41            220   21  221            109       5    4     11   10
    9   40   41             28   45   53            65       5    4      7    2
    9   40   41             36   77   85            83       5    4      9    2
    9   40   41             44  117  125            101       5    4     11    2
    9   40   41             48   55   73            75       5    4      8    3
    9   40   41             56   33   65            67       5    4      7    4
    9   40   41             60   11   61            59       5    4      6    5
    9   40   41             60   91  109            93       5    4     10    3
    9   40   41             72   65   97            85       5    4      9    4
    9   40   41             80   39   89            77       5    4      8    5
    9   40   41             84   13   85            69       5    4      7    6
    9   40   41             88  105  137            103       5    4     11    4
   11   60   61            112   15  113            95       6    5      8    7
   11   60   61            132   85  157            127       6    5     11    6
   11   60   61            140   51  149            117       6    5     10    7
   11   60   61            144   17  145            107       6    5      9    8
   11   60   61             16   63   65            89       6    5      8    1
   11   60   61            176   57  185            129       6    5     11    8
   11   60   61            180   19  181            119       6    5     10    9
   11   60   61             20   99  101            111       6    5     10    1
   11   60   61            220   21  221            131       6    5     11   10
   11   60   61             36   77   85            101       6    5      9    2
   11   60   61             44  117  125            123       6    5     11    2
   11   60   61             48   55   73            91       6    5      8    3
   11   60   61             56   33   65            81       6    5      7    4
   11   60   61             60   91  109            113       6    5     10    3
   11   60   61             72   65   97            103       6    5      9    4
   11   60   61             80   39   89            93       6    5      8    5
   11   60   61             84   13   85            83       6    5      7    6
   11   60   61             88  105  137            125       6    5     11    4
   12   35   37            105   88  137            97       6    1     11    4
   12   35   37             11   60   61            67       6    1      6    5
   12   35   37            117   44  125            87       6    1     11    2
   12   35   37             13   84   85            79       6    1      7    6
   12   35   37             15  112  113            91       6    1      8    7
   12   35   37             17  144  145            103       6    1      9    8
   12   35   37             19  180  181            115       6    1     10    9
   12   35   37             21  220  221            127       6    1     11   10
   12   35   37             33   56   65            69       6    1      7    4
   12   35   37             39   80   89            81       6    1      8    5
   12   35   37             45   28   53            59       6    1      7    2
   12   35   37             51  140  149            105       6    1     10    7
   12   35   37             55   48   73            71       6    1      8    3
   12   35   37             57  176  185            117       6    1     11    8
   12   35   37             63   16   65            61       6    1      8    1
   12   35   37             65   72   97            83       6    1      9    4
   12   35   37             77   36   85            73       6    1      9    2
   12   35   37             85  132  157            107       6    1     11    6
   12   35   37             91   60  109            85       6    1     10    3
   12   35   37              9   40   41            55       6    1      5    4
   12   35   37             99   20  101            75       6    1     10    1
   13   84   85            112   15  113            111       7    6      8    7
   13   84   85            132   85  157            149       7    6     11    6
   13   84   85            140   51  149            137       7    6     10    7
   13   84   85            144   17  145            125       7    6      9    8
   13   84   85            176   57  185            151       7    6     11    8
   13   84   85            180   19  181            139       7    6     10    9
   13   84   85             20   99  101            131       7    6     10    1
   13   84   85            220   21  221            153       7    6     11   10
   13   84   85             44  117  125            145       7    6     11    2
   13   84   85             60   91  109            133       7    6     10    3
   13   84   85             72   65   97            121       7    6      9    4
   13   84   85             80   39   89            109       7    6      8    5
   13   84   85             88  105  137            147       7    6     11    4
   15  112  113            132   85  157            171       8    7     11    6
   15  112  113            140   51  149            157       8    7     10    7
   15  112  113            144   17  145            143       8    7      9    8
   15  112  113            176   57  185            173       8    7     11    8
   15  112  113            180   19  181            159       8    7     10    9
   15  112  113            220   21  221            175       8    7     11   10
   15  112  113             44  117  125            167       8    7     11    2
   15  112  113             88  105  137            169       8    7     11    4
   16   63   65            105   88  137            127       8    1     11    4
   16   63   65            117   44  125            113       8    1     11    2
   16   63   65             13   84   85            105       8    1      7    6
   16   63   65             15  112  113            121       8    1      8    7
   16   63   65             17  144  145            137       8    1      9    8
   16   63   65             19  180  181            153       8    1     10    9
   16   63   65             21  220  221            169       8    1     11   10
   16   63   65             39   80   89            107       8    1      8    5
   16   63   65             51  140  149            139       8    1     10    7
   16   63   65             55   48   73            93       8    1      8    3
   16   63   65             57  176  185            155       8    1     11    8
   16   63   65             65   72   97            109       8    1      9    4
   16   63   65             77   36   85            95       8    1      9    2
   16   63   65             85  132  157            141       8    1     11    6
   16   63   65             91   60  109            111       8    1     10    3
   16   63   65             99   20  101            97       8    1     10    1
   17  144  145            132   85  157            193       9    8     11    6
   17  144  145            140   51  149            177       9    8     10    7
   17  144  145            176   57  185            195       9    8     11    8
   17  144  145            180   19  181            179       9    8     10    9
   17  144  145            220   21  221            197       9    8     11   10
   19  180  181            176   57  185            217      10    9     11    8
   19  180  181            220   21  221            219      10    9     11   10
   20   21   29            105   88  137            89       5    2     11    4
   20   21   29             11   60   61            57       5    2      6    5
   20   21   29            117   44  125            83       5    2     11    2
   20   21   29             13   84   85            67       5    2      7    6
   20   21   29             15  112  113            77       5    2      8    7
   20   21   29             17  144  145            87       5    2      9    8
   20   21   29             19  180  181            97       5    2     10    9
   20   21   29             21  220  221            107       5    2     11   10
   20   21   29             33   56   65            61       5    2      7    4
   20   21   29             35   12   37            45       5    2      6    1
   20   21   29             39   80   89            71       5    2      8    5
   20   21   29             45   28   53            55       5    2      7    2
   20   21   29             51  140  149            91       5    2     10    7
   20   21   29             55   48   73            65       5    2      8    3
   20   21   29             57  176  185            101       5    2     11    8
   20   21   29             63   16   65            59       5    2      8    1
   20   21   29             65   72   97            75       5    2      9    4
   20   21   29             77   36   85            69       5    2      9    2
   20   21   29             85  132  157            95       5    2     11    6
   20   21   29             91   60  109            79       5    2     10    3
   20   21   29              9   40   41            47       5    2      5    4
   20   21   29             99   20  101            73       5    2     10    1
   20   99  101            105   88  137            157      10    1     11    4
   20   99  101            117   44  125            139      10    1     11    2
   20   99  101             15  112  113            151      10    1      8    7
   20   99  101             17  144  145            171      10    1      9    8
   20   99  101             19  180  181            191      10    1     10    9
   20   99  101             21  220  221            211      10    1     11   10
   20   99  101             51  140  149            173      10    1     10    7
   20   99  101             57  176  185            193      10    1     11    8
   20   99  101             85  132  157            175      10    1     11    6
   20   99  101             91   60  109            137      10    1     10    3
   28   45   53            105   88  137            119       7    2     11    4
   28   45   53             11   60   61            79       7    2      6    5
   28   45   53            117   44  125            109       7    2     11    2
   28   45   53             13   84   85            93       7    2      7    6
   28   45   53             15  112  113            107       7    2      8    7
   28   45   53             17  144  145            121       7    2      9    8
   28   45   53             19  180  181            135       7    2     10    9
   28   45   53             21  220  221            149       7    2     11   10
   28   45   53             33   56   65            83       7    2      7    4
   28   45   53             39   80   89            97       7    2      8    5
   28   45   53             51  140  149            125       7    2     10    7
   28   45   53             55   48   73            87       7    2      8    3
   28   45   53             57  176  185            139       7    2     11    8
   28   45   53             63   16   65            77       7    2      8    1
   28   45   53             65   72   97            101       7    2      9    4
   28   45   53             77   36   85            91       7    2      9    2
   28   45   53             85  132  157            129       7    2     11    6
   28   45   53             91   60  109            105       7    2     10    3
   28   45   53             99   20  101            95       7    2     10    1
   33   56   65            112   15  113            109       7    4      8    7
   33   56   65            132   85  157            139       7    4     11    6
   33   56   65            140   51  149            131       7    4     10    7
   33   56   65            144   17  145            123       7    4      9    8
   33   56   65            176   57  185            145       7    4     11    8
   33   56   65            180   19  181            137       7    4     10    9
   33   56   65             20   99  101            113       7    4     10    1
   33   56   65            220   21  221            151       7    4     11   10
   33   56   65             36   77   85            105       7    4      9    2
   33   56   65             44  117  125            127       7    4     11    2
   33   56   65             48   55   73            97       7    4      8    3
   33   56   65             60   91  109            119       7    4     10    3
   33   56   65             72   65   97            111       7    4      9    4
   33   56   65             80   39   89            103       7    4      8    5
   33   56   65             84   13   85            95       7    4      7    6
   33   56   65             88  105  137            133       7    4     11    4
   36   77   85            105   88  137            149       9    2     11    4
   36   77   85            117   44  125            135       9    2     11    2
   36   77   85             15  112  113            137       9    2      8    7
   36   77   85             17  144  145            155       9    2      9    8
   36   77   85             19  180  181            173       9    2     10    9
   36   77   85             21  220  221            191       9    2     11   10
   36   77   85             39   80   89            123       9    2      8    5
   36   77   85             51  140  149            159       9    2     10    7
   36   77   85             57  176  185            177       9    2     11    8
   36   77   85             65   72   97            127       9    2      9    4
   36   77   85             85  132  157            163       9    2     11    6
   36   77   85             91   60  109            131       9    2     10    3
   36   77   85             99   20  101            117       9    2     10    1
   39   80   89            112   15  113            125       8    5      8    7
   39   80   89            132   85  157            161       8    5     11    6
   39   80   89            140   51  149            151       8    5     10    7
   39   80   89            144   17  145            141       8    5      9    8
   39   80   89            176   57  185            167       8    5     11    8
   39   80   89            180   19  181            157       8    5     10    9
   39   80   89             20   99  101            133       8    5     10    1
   39   80   89            220   21  221            173       8    5     11   10
   39   80   89             44  117  125            149       8    5     11    2
   39   80   89             60   91  109            139       8    5     10    3
   39   80   89             72   65   97            129       8    5      9    4
   39   80   89             88  105  137            155       8    5     11    4
   44  117  125            105   88  137            179      11    2     11    4
   44  117  125             17  144  145            189      11    2      9    8
   44  117  125             19  180  181            211      11    2     10    9
   44  117  125             21  220  221            233      11    2     11   10
   44  117  125             51  140  149            193      11    2     10    7
   44  117  125             57  176  185            215      11    2     11    8
   44  117  125             85  132  157            197      11    2     11    6
   48   55   73            105   88  137            141       8    3     11    4
   48   55   73            117   44  125            131       8    3     11    2
   48   55   73             13   84   85            107       8    3      7    6
   48   55   73             15  112  113            123       8    3      8    7
   48   55   73             17  144  145            139       8    3      9    8
   48   55   73             19  180  181            155       8    3     10    9
   48   55   73             21  220  221            171       8    3     11   10
   48   55   73             39   80   89            113       8    3      8    5
   48   55   73             51  140  149            145       8    3     10    7
   48   55   73             57  176  185            161       8    3     11    8
   48   55   73             65   72   97            119       8    3      9    4
   48   55   73             77   36   85            109       8    3      9    2
   48   55   73             85  132  157            151       8    3     11    6
   48   55   73             91   60  109            125       8    3     10    3
   48   55   73             99   20  101            115       8    3     10    1
   51  140  149            132   85  157            205      10    7     11    6
   51  140  149            176   57  185            211      10    7     11    8
   51  140  149            180   19  181            197      10    7     10    9
   51  140  149            220   21  221            217      10    7     11   10
   57  176  185            220   21  221            239      11    8     11   10
   60   91  109            105   88  137            171      10    3     11    4
   60   91  109            117   44  125            157      10    3     11    2
   60   91  109             15  112  113            153      10    3      8    7
   60   91  109             17  144  145            173      10    3      9    8
   60   91  109             19  180  181            193      10    3     10    9
   60   91  109             21  220  221            213      10    3     11   10
   60   91  109             51  140  149            179      10    3     10    7
   60   91  109             57  176  185            199      10    3     11    8
   60   91  109             85  132  157            185      10    3     11    6
   65   72   97            112   15  113            139       9    4      8    7
   65   72   97            132   85  157            173       9    4     11    6
   65   72   97            140   51  149            165       9    4     10    7
   65   72   97            144   17  145            157       9    4      9    8
   65   72   97            176   57  185            183       9    4     11    8
   65   72   97            180   19  181            175       9    4     10    9
   65   72   97             20   99  101            135       9    4     10    1
   65   72   97            220   21  221            193       9    4     11   10
   65   72   97             44  117  125            153       9    4     11    2
    p    q    r             x    y    z           sqrt       a    b      c    d
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, trivially so. Take $(3k, 4k, 5k)$ and $(20k, 21k, 29k)$, both Pythagorean triples. Then $3k\times20k+4k\times21k+5k\times29k=(17k)^2$, giving an infinite family of solutions.

Comment: How about the case of non-trival?

Comment: By the way thank you for the trivial case, I never thought of that